# Loading Data in R with zoo

Tags: r, zoo, quantitative-finance

I've figured out how to load historical financial [data](https://www.google.com/finance?q=slb&ei=SS1RU8jfAobLsAeqrgE) from Google using the following code:

```
slb <- read.table( "slb.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", col.names=c("date","open","high","low","close","volume") )
slb$date <- as.Date( slb$date, "%d-%b-%y" )
slb <- zoo( slb )
```

This works fine, but I'd like to accomplish this using the `read.zoo()` function, but I keep getting errors about "bad rows". Here is what I had tried using `read.zoo()`.

```
slb <- read.zoo( "slb.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", format="%d-%b-%y" )
```

Do you guys have any ideas for a one-liner? Thanks!

Comment: There is an extraneous + sign in the first line of code. The data link provided does not point to a csv file. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Okay, thanks! I didn't know how to directly link a CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to do it: `read.zoo("http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NYSE%3ASLB&ei=SjFRU6jLKKGkwAPs2AE&output=csv", format="%d-%B-%y", header=TRUE, sep=",")`
Note the capital `%B`...

Comment: Unbelievable. I thought `%b` signified an abbreviated month. Thanks sooo much. I was struggling with this for a good hour.